# Changing date to days with update statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table that lists Dates as 110427 in Date col.
I Have a days col, which is days form today.
This sql gets all my dates:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT date FROM test.op;
```

This Sql gets days from today:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS('20110430') -  TO_DAYS(NOW());
```

How do I loop an update?
Where result would

```
     Date    Days
    110430   3
    110530   33
```

Would use an if or case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
UPDATE   MyTable
SET      Days = TO_DAYS(date) - TO_DAYS(NOW());
```

This would update each row's `Days` column to have the value from the the row's `date` column run through your subtraction.

Comment: I thought of that but would it make sense to do difference math once then do updates?

Comment: @Johan: In Mysql 5.5.11 , '110410' does get changed to usable form. In my case 20110410.

Comment: @Johan: have you tested it before downvoting?

Comment: @Johan: so why the downvote if it actually works, and you hadn't tested it?

Comment: @cambell, tried undoing the downvote, but it's locked in until further edit. Was voting based on prior experience, must have mixed up stuff. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE test.op SET days = TO_DAYS(date) - TO_DAYS(NOW());
```

This will set the `days` column with the difference between the date and now for all records in the table `test.op`. Adjust for your exact schema.

Comment: I dont want days to equal todays date but rather difference.

Comment: I was think to math once then update all that are of a certain date.